# Cannot retrieve HTML5 Video load percentage

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm attempting to create a simple loading bar for a video element. I've followed as much of the information I can find on this issue but continue to have trouble displaying the loaded percentage in the progress bar.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anater/pen/WvYver)

HTML

```
<video id="preview-vid" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
  <source src="link-to-video">
</video>

<progress id="bgVidProgress" max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

JS

```
var vid = document.querySelector("#preview-vid");
var progress = document.getElementById("bgVidProgress");

vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
  progress.value = Math.round((this.buffered.end(0) / this.duration) * 100);
});
```

Edit: This issue only appears in Safari, but not Firefox & Chrome.

Edit: Updated code

Comment: `vid.buffered.end` will just find the first loaded segment, not the whole video, unless those are the same.

Comment: Do you mean a buffering progress bar? [Like so](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPqoqP)? Remove the `load` wrapper and round `loadedPercentage` before assigning it to `progress.value`.

Comment: @Xufox your solution is sound, but for some reason only works in Firefox. The latest versions of Safari and Chrome (on Mac) do not alter the load bar.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no "load" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) for a video element, so your "progress" event listener never gets added. Just this should be enough...

```
var vid = document.querySelector("#preview-vid");
var progress = document.getElementById("bgVidProgress");

vid.addEventListener('progress', function(){
  var loadedPercentage = (vid.buffered.end(0) / vid.duration) * 100;
  console.log(loadedPercentage);
  progress.value = loadedPercentage;
});
```

Now, as @dandavis points out, vid.buffered.end(0) only shows the first segment. So if someone were to skip to the middle of the video before the first part has loaded, there may be a big gap in the buffered section, with a large buffered chunk towards the end. As your code is written, that will never show up in the progress bar.

In your case, the video is pretty short, so you probably won't notice. But for general purposes, it's better to have a canvas and loop through the vid.buffered segments, drawing in the sections that are loaded.

Comment: In OP, the load event is attached to the document.

Comment: As @Kaiido said, the load event is attached to the document to make sure the element has initialized before setting a listener to it. I suppose that may not be necessary, but that was the purpose for it. Your solution causes the same issue, no load progress in Safari or Chrome - only Firefox works. What's problematic is the spec for Safari & Chrome claim to support obtaining these values.

Comment: Somehow I missed that. But it was necessary to remove it anyway for FF/Chrome because the code might run AFTER document load, and then you've missed it. Will take another look.

Comment: It works just fine for me in Chrome 44 and Safari 7.